# how recursion works and prints these ascendin descending numbers

Tags: c++, recursion

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int sub() {
    int a;
    a=5;
    return a;
     }
void fact(int x) {
    if(x>=1)
    {
         cout<<"counter:"<<x<<endl;
        fact(x-1);
        cout<<"after emptying stack"<<x<<endl;         
    }
    cout<<"check"<<endl;
}

int main() {
    fact(sub());
}
```

Output:

```
counter:3
counter:2
counter:1
check
after emptying stack1
check
after emptying stack2
check
after emptying stack3
check
```

I have debugged the program but after the `if` statement, it should stop and go back to `main` but after complete if it return to again `cout` and how did the program print number after `if` statement terminates? Please explain ([SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1qzU.png))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplify your example first: your main function is basically calling fact(5) (since sub is always returning 5).

Here's a dissection of how the recursive calls are done:

```
-- 5 >= 1 is true -- 
fact(5):
    counter:\n fact(4) after emptying stack 5\ncheck\n
-- 4 >= 1 is true -- 
fact(4):
    counter:\n fact(3) after emptying stack 4\ncheck\n
-- 3 >= 1 is true -- 
fact(3):
    counter:\n fact(2) after emptying stack 3\ncheck\n
-- 2 >= 1 is true -- 
fact(2): 
    counter:\n fact(1) after emptying stack 2\ncheck\n
-- 1 >= 1 is true -- 
fact(1):
    counter:\n fact(0) after emptying stack 1\ncheck\n
-- 0 >= 1 is false -- 
fact(0):
    check\n
```

Now replace the calls from the bottom to the top:

```
fact(1):
    counter:\n check\n after emptying stack 1\ncheck\n
fact(2): 
    counter:\n counter:\n check after emptying stack 1\ncheck\n after emptying stack 2\n
fact(3): 
    counter:\n -- above here -- after emptying stack 3\ncheck\n
...
```